# Finding a curve that lies on the arbitrary sphere given $\alpha(0)$ and $\alpha'(0)$.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Find a curve $\alpha : (−ε,ε) → \Sigma$ on the sphere which has $\alpha(0) = (1,0,0)$ and $\alpha′(0) = (0, 5, 6)$.

I'm unsure how to approach this. I know the parametarization of a sphere, and obviously the bases of the tangent space, but I don't know if this will help me?

Answer (score 0):

In general, for two orthogonal unit vectors $p, Z \in \mathbb{R}^3$, the map
$$ \gamma: s \mapsto p\cos s + Z\sin s $$
parametrizes a unit speed curve on the unit circle with $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\dot\gamma(0) = Z.$ Can you adapt this to your case?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you. Is there a justification for it? Obviously I can see why it works but there is no reference to it in my notes and textbooks. I don't want it to appear that I picked it out of thin air!

Comment: Well, I don't know what the best justification is, but could think of it this way: we know that in the plane, the unit circle can be parametrized as $s \mapsto (\cos s, \sin s) = e_1\cos s + e_2\sin s$ where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we are considering the plane spanned by the vectors $p$ and $Z$, which intersects the sphere in a great circle, the parametrization of which is in some sense obtained by replacing the basis vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$ by the basis vectors $p$ and $Z$ for our plane.

Answer (score 0):

Let us place here the conditions for future referencing :

$$V(0)=(1,0,0)^T  \ (a) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \  V'(0)=(0,5,6)^T \ (b) \tag{1}$$

There is an obvious candidate

- for the trajectory : a *great circle* of the sphere, obtained here by a rotation of the equator by an angle $a$ around the $x$ axis.
- in a second step, its cinematics : how must this trajectory be parametrized ? It suffices clearly, thinking to a uniform angular speed) to take $kt$ instead of $t$ ; all this gives :

$$V(t)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0& \ \ 0\\
0&\cos(a)&-\sin(a)\\
0&\sin(a)&\ \ \cos(a)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\cos(kt)\\
\sin(kt)\\
0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(kt)\\ \cos(a)\sin(kt)\\
\sin(a)\sin(kt)\end{pmatrix} \tag{2}$$

We have thus to determine constants $a$ and $k$ in order that conditions (1) are fulfilled.

The first condition is clearly fullfilled.

It remains to comply to 2nd condition (b).

As :

$$V'(t)=(-k \sin(t), k \cos(a) \cos(kt), k \sin(a)\cos(kt))^T.$$

Taking $t=0$ yields, by identification with the values of the 2nd condition $(0,5,6)^T$ :

$$k \cos(a)=5  \ \ (a) \ \ \text{and} \ \  k \sin(a)=6 \ \ (b). \tag{3}$$

Taking the quotient of (b) by (a) gives $\tan(a)=6/5$ : Thus $a$ can be taken as $a_0=\mathrm{atan}(6/5)$.

Taking the square of (a) and (b) and adding them, one gets $k_0= \sqrt{61}\approx 7.8$ (taking $k=-\sqrt{61}$ would make going the other way).

Thus the solution is given by (2) with $k=k_0$ and $a=a_0$.

Last thing : The interval of variation for parameter $t$ ? You must not pass twice on the same point, thus, take $t_{lim}$ (your $\varepsilon$) such that $\sqrt{61}t_{lim}<\pi \ \iff \ t_{lim}<\pi/\sqrt{61}$, for example $t_{lim}=0.4$.