# Finding parametrized curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Unit sphere parametrized as $x(θ, ϕ) = (\sin (θ) \cos (ϕ), \sin (θ) \sin (ϕ), \cos (θ))$, how would one find a parametric curve which has $α(0)=(1,0,0)$ and $α'(0)=(0,3,4)$?

Comment: Check out [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013177/finding-a-curve-that-lies-on-the-arbitrary-sphere-given-alpha0-and-alpha/3013182?noredirect=1#comment6214273_3013182).

Answer (score 0):

Define $v_0=(1,0,0)$ and $v_1=\tfrac1{5}(0,3,4)$. Then
$$
\alpha(t) = \cos(5t)v_0+\sin(5t)v_1
$$
is the curve you want.